# How to display Javascript function in an HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am trying to create a counting table for kids. I want to display a button which will display the counting in a list. I can get it to print to the page but i want to print it in paragraph tag in my HTML please have a look and suggest me the solution.

```
<p id="main"></p>
<button onclick="counting();" >Counting 1 to 10</button>

var counting = function(){
    var myCount = 1;
    while(myCount < 11){
    var countTotal = myCount;
    document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = countTotal;
    //print(countTotal);
    myCount++;
    }
return countTotal;
}
```

Comment: It seems you already putting the result in the paragraph (assuming the JS code is actually in a `<script>`, not like in your example). What is the problem with your code? The title of your question seems to suggest you want to show the *source* of the function itself, but that might just be unfortunate wording.

Comment: Change this line to show complete list: `document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = countTotal;` to `document.getElementById('main').innerHTML += countTotal + "<br />"`

Comment: With your js code you are only going to see the end count as the while loop is going to continue running (and blocking the UI) till it ends, only after it ends are you going to see the count in the html element updated. If you want to visually see it increment you will need to use a timer (setTimeout/setInterval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @Lal's answer is **the answer** (I wrote the same in a comment).

#### But, I suggest another way:

Instead of using the `while` cycle you can use a `setInterval`, in my opinion to create a **counting table for kids** the user experience is more important then performance:

take a look to this code:

```
var counting = function(){
    var myCount = 1;
    document.getElementById('main').innerHTML += myCount + "<br/>";
    var _timeout = setInterval(function(){
        myCount++;
        document.getElementById('main').innerHTML += myCount + "<br/>";
        if(myCount == 10) clearTimeout(_timeout)
    },1000)
}
```

This function set a timer that every 1000 milliseconds (1 second) show you a new number so as to allow time for the child to count.

Look this example: https://jsfiddle.net/Frogmouth/bke47w3u/2/

`if(myCount == 10) clearTimeout(_timeout)` stop the timer when `myCount` is `10`.

#### Add Cell to a table:

If you need to add the number like cell of table simply change the html container `#main`:

```
<table id="main"></table>
```

and the html printed by `.innerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById('main').innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + myCount + "</td></tr>";
```

This show you a table with 1 cell for each rows for a total of 10 rows.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Frogmouth/bke47w3u/5/

Comment: The _timeout is definitely make sense. The other thing i got to know is that we can use += with getElementById function. But i would like to know is there a way we can append it into the table to make it look good?

Comment: In a table? Yes you can, I edit my answer, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ok2fwa4/1/)

You have to append the innerHTML each time you are performing the count. So you have to set the innerHTML as below

```
document.getElementById('main').innerHTML += countTotal + "<br />";
```